# Will Oracle Universal Installer mess up my existing database setup?

Tags: java, oracle, odp.net

I'm asking here because I haven't been able to get a clean answer from Oracle, so I wanted to see if there were any Oracle experts out here!

As a high-level overview of what I'm trying to accomplish, I want to get a recently-moved two-way interface to authenticate through the served ASMX file to authenticate the username and password against an Oracle DB. I am getting an 'Invalid Credentials' SOAP Header Exception error on the web interface. In reviewing the setup of the old IIS server, I see there's an Oracle Data Provider installed on it. When I search for this ODP.Net provider, I see it's included with a configuration tool called the Oracle Universal Installer.

When I begin the install, I see it copying over a bunch of java JRE files, so I exited out as I was concerned it would mess up my existing setup. (This is the OXI server, not the App/DB server)

So my question is...would installing Oracle Universal Installer mess up my existing environment? (I realize this question is extremely specific to a particular environment) I've taken a snapshot of both my OXI and DB servers as a just in-case...I guess I am looking for a little extra comfort before continuing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In terms of Java I don't think so. The installer copies java files into sub-folder of your Oracle folder and that's it.

However, for other components it might do a lot and also break your existing application. It may overwrite the ODP.NET provider, change your `PATH` variable, etc.

Your question has to be more specific.

Comment: As I understand it, all of that would be specific to the OXI server though, correct? I'm assuming it would prompt me before it attempts to connect to the DB? My biggest worry is impacting the DB...I can roll the OXI back by restoring a checkpoint in Hyper-V, but I didn't want it to touch the DB or make changes I cannot rollback easily.

Comment: I don't think the DB will be touched at all.